# Creating a simple .apk package for android devices to open a url

Tags: android, kotlin

The requirement is to create an android package that simply opens a URL. The real requirement is to have a URL "shortcut" available on 1000's of android devices' home screens. I cannot do this via google chrome bookmarks -> add to homepage as this setting cannot be configured/pushed to all devices via MDM. It seems then like I would have to create a package to open this url which could then be published to these tablets.

Does anybody have an easy way to accomplish this? I have 0 kotlin experience.

I simply want to be able to tap a button on the homescreen and open a URL, doesn't matter how/where it opens (either in-browser or an app window).

Similar to this tut, however I don't need/want a button to open the URL. Just want it to open immediately.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url-using-kotlin

I've got android studio downloaded and am trying to work through it but this can't be as difficult as I'm making it over here.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you can ignore everything about inflating layouts etc and simply empty out your MainActivity and just leave an Intent to launch your given website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want an app which have such behaviour:

1. You open the app
2. App is opening some URL which you'll define in the code.
3. After that app is closing.

If this is correct, you just need to define Activity's onCreate() method like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val url = "https://google.com" // Here is your URL
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))

    startActivity(intent) // Starting activity which will open this URL

    finish() // Finish your app's Activity in order to close the app.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I start a new project with an empty views activity. Modify the main function as you show and am getting build errors. Any idea?
https://imgur.com/LEKzeEi

Comment: It is unresolved reference for this line: val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))

Comment: Yes, you need to import this classes in the start of the file: 
`import android.content.Intent`
`import android.net.Uri`